# Woocommerce check if email already created order recently

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, user-registration, email-verification

I'm using woocommerce for my client to sell product worldwide. We don't force to create an account during the checkout so the user can buy without registration. Some times we get multiple order from the same user in few minutes, so i'm wondering if it is possible during the checkout to verify if from the same email we received an order (completed with payment) in the last 10 minutes. In case the email already exist in the last orders the system must block the checkout process.
We use stripe for payments and we lose money when we have to refund the user for multiple orders.
Thanks

Comment: WooCommerce and other 3rd party plugin/theme dev support is off topic and not in this stacks scope. You should ask via their official support routes or in their groups and communities.

Comment: @TomJNowell, sorry, I didn't notice your comment. Should I retract my answer?

Comment: @Abhik no, it may still be useful for others, and you can still be upvoted

Answer (score 1):

You can create a helper function for that which qurries the orders for given email and created less than 10 mins ago.

```
function wpse407278_check_if_ordered_in_last_10_mins( $email ) {
    
    if ( !isset($email) || empty($email) ) {
        return false;
    }
    
    $args = array(
        'customer' => $email,
        'date_created' => '>' . ( time() - strtotime('-10 minutes') ),
    );
    $orders = wc_get_orders( $args );

    if ( empty( $orders ) ) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

This will return `true` if the customer has orderd within last 10 minutes and `false` otherwise.

Comment: Thanks @abhik for your answer, this helper function will work live during the checkout? In the array the "customer@domain.com" are static or variable?
I have to send in the frontend a message to the user if the result of the query are true.

Comment: @JhonnyStanfield It'll work anywhere provided you pass the customer email. Something like this.. `wpse407278_check_if_ordered_in_last_10_mins( $email )`.